# Is the list of words with a contracted "not" closed?

Tags: grammar

In this question closed means *can't be added to*, such as the list of pronouns, *I*, *you*, etc. can't be added to, but nouns can; a hundred years ago there was no internet or a word for fractals.

So, is the list of *-n't* words closed? It seems to be as you can't just attach it to any old verb. *hasn't* is fine but *workn't* isn't. I have found many lists of *-n't* words but none that claim to be complete, only some that say they have the commonly used words.

In this question I used three such words without realising I'd used that many! *can't* (three times), *hasn't* (my example word) and *isn't*.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:List_of_English_contractions looks finite to me.

Comment: @mitch but that list is a pile of pants! It doesn't even have *daren't* , for example!

Comment: or dasn't or mustn't've or innit or summat. But nobody's perfect. But anyway, you have the answer, contraction of not doesn't work with an open set, done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, *not* only contracts with auxiliary verbs. There may be some exceptions. For example, it could be argued that in *I haven't the time or the energy* the verb *HAVE* is not an auxiliary. But note that this verb *can* used as an auxiliary. So we could probably reformulate that as *only verbs that are sometimes auxiliaries* can contract with *not*.

The auxiliary verbs in English are *BE, HAVE, DO* and the modal auxiliaries, the central members of which are:

- *CAN, COULD, SHALL, SHOULD, WILL, WOULD, MAY, MIGHT* and *MUST*

There are also a few so-called marginal auxiliaries:

- *DARE, NEED, OUGHT, USED*

I may have missed one or two marginal auxiliaries there.

In short, the verbs that can contract with *not* in English are best thought of as a small closed class. Although there is always some change on the periphery of the class (consider *USED* for example), the English auxiliaries are generally considered to be a closed class.

Comment: A _not_ negating a VP requires an auxiliary verb; that's why **workn't* is ungrammatical -- **work not* is ungrammatical already. So they naturally contract with auxiliary verbs, and there is already a short list of those. And not all of them, either -- _%mayn't_ is rare to nonexistent in the US, for instance. When enough people decide different, it'll change.

Comment: @john yes, % *usen't* is vey rare too. But does occur.

Comment: Not in English speech, at least in the USA. I've never heard it. And I'm not sure how to pronounce _mayn't_; it looks like it oughta rhyme with _ain't_, but I want to make it two syllables. Whatever, I don't think I've heard it often enough to tell.

Comment: @JohnLawler I'm in the UK and on the (very) few occasions I've had to, I've always used one syllable - like _maint_.

Comment: I’m sure I’ve heard *mayn’t* and when I have it’s always been pronounced as *may-ent* I think back when children were constantly corrected to ask “may we” instead of ‘can we’, “mayn’t  we” was much more common.

Comment: @JohnLawler [Here's a dictionary entry from Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/usent)

Comment: As in "This is usen't for curing, but for preventing the disease"? Or as in "I'm usen't to that any more"? This is construction-based, and it only contracts under specific syntactic conditions; it's not just a string substitute.

Comment: @JohnLawler Yeah, no. Like the verb *used* in general, it only exists in the past tense and isn't synchronically related to the verb *use*. Like all the freaky half-modally verbs that don't make English neat and tidy, but make it interesting I suppose. (I prefer the ones that make things neat, but there you go)

Comment: In USAan English, the tense construction _used to_  is fused into /yustə/ and is not separable. Since it's already reified, the verb _used_ is not available, however pronounced, as a negative contraction site. No doubt British syntax, being much more variable, has different constraints and affordances.

Comment: @JohnLawler Yes, I think that must be right.

Comment: @JohnLawler Can I ask you a question about conditionals/interrogatives?

Comment: @Araucaria Sure. I don't guarantee any answer, though.

Comment: @JohnLawler Are you familiar with an analysis of interrogatives (maybe  using very different terminology) where 'polar' questions involve a positive/negative answer (eg  "Is Bob here?"). And 'alternative' questions set out an A or B answer ("Is Bob dead or alive?"). And under which 'polar alternative' questions explicilty state both alternatives of a polar question ("Is Bob here or not?") ? [Could take many forms such as "Is Bob here or not here?", or "Is Bob here, or is Bob not here?"]

Comment: Not as far as I know; the main syntactic difference is between Y/N and WH questions. Internal structure doesn't really affect question syntax much.

Comment: @JohnLawler So some people would say that for example the verb *doubt* will take Y/N subordinate clauses but not 'A or B' clauses. So you can have "I doubt whether Bob puched Bill", but not "I doubt whether Bob punched Bill or not"

Comment: _Doubt_ already announces the negative polarity; it's not surprising it deselects the disjunctive negation. BTW, if you change _whether_ to _if_, the clause has the same constraint.